# cgo: exec /missing-cc: fork/exec /missing-cc: no such file or directory

Tags: golang, docker, sqlite3, dockerfile

Использую либу github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 для работы с SQLite, при докеризации выдает вот такую ошибку

> [build 7/7] RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 go build   -o /app /src/cmd:

> #12 8.968 # github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3

> #12 8.968 cgo: exec /missing-cc: fork/exec /missing-cc: no such file or directory

Вот докерфайл

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
  ca-certificates \
  git \
  bash

WORKDIR /src

COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 go build \
  -o /app /src/cmd

FROM scratch AS final

COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=build /app /app
COPY --from=build /src/reminderbot.toml /config.toml
COPY --from=build /src/persons.json /persons.json

EXPOSE 1243

ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app" ]
CMD ["-config", "/config.toml"]
```

Уже часа два гуглю, надежды все меньше

Comment: если вы используете `alpine` образ, попробуйте поставить `gcc` и `musl-dev` или перейти на не `apline`

Comment: А как поставить, если не секрет, немног оне понял

Comment: добавить в apk команду после `bash` просто добавить `gcc musl-dev`

Comment: On Windows, installing TDM-GCC fixed this problem